# SQL Query not Retrieving All Rows in C# Application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure created in my SQL Server 2012 database that selects data from multiple tables. In C#, I use this procedure to show data in a datagridview.

Issue: when I execute the query in SQL Server, I get the correct result which returns 3 rows, but in C#, it returns only 2 rows.

Query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Employee.Employee_No AS 'Badge'
    ,Employee.Employee_Name_Ar AS 'Emp Name'
    ,Employee.Basic_Salary AS 'Basic'
    ,Employee.Current_Salary AS 'Current'
    ,Attendance.Present
    ,Attendance.Leave
    ,Attendance.Othe_Leave AS 'OL'
    ,Pay_Slip.Salary_Amount AS 'Sal. Amt.'
    ,(ISNULL(Pay_Slip.OverTime1_Amount, 0.00) + ISNULL(Pay_Slip.OverTime2_Amount, 0.00)) AS 'O/T Amt.'
    ,(ISNULL(Pay_Slip.Salary_Amount, 0.00) + ISNULL(ISNULL(Pay_Slip.OverTime1_Amount, 0.00) + ISNULL(Pay_Slip.OverTime2_Amount, 0.00), 0.00)) AS 'Sal. & O/T'
    ,Pay_Slip.Trasnport AS 'Allow'
    ,Pay_Slip.CostofLiving AS 'O.Allow'
    ,Pay_Slip.Gross_Salary AS 'T Salary'
    ,Pay_Slip.Insurance1_Amount AS 'ss 7%'
    ,Pay_Slip.Insurance2_Amount AS 'ss 11%'
    ,(ISNULL(Pay_Slip.Insurance1_Amount, 0.00) + ISNULL(Pay_Slip.Insurance2_Amount, 0.00)) AS 'Total s.s'
    ,Pay_Slip.Tax
    ,Pay_Slip.Personal_Loans AS 'Advance'
    ,Pay_Slip.Other_Deductions AS 'Ded.'
    ,Pay_Slip.Net_Salary AS 'Net'
FROM Pay_Slip
LEFT JOIN Employee ON Pay_Slip.Employee_No = Employee.Employee_No
LEFT JOIN Attendance ON Pay_Slip.Employee_No = Attendance.Employee_No
WHERE Pay_Slip.Month = '5'
    AND Pay_Slip.Year = '2020'
    AND Attendance.Month = '5'
    AND Attendance.Year = '2020'
```

Executing this query in SQL Server returns 3 rows which are the employee slips on May-2020 (They all have values in May-2020).

C# code:

```cs
private void dateTimePicker_ReportDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime date = dateTimePicker_ReportDate.Value;

        String Month = dateTimePicker_ReportDate.Value.ToString("MM");
        String Year = dateTimePicker_ReportDate.Value.ToString("yyyy");

        String str = "server=localhost;database=EasyManagementSystem;User Id=Jaz;Password=Jaz@2020;Integrated Security=True;";

        String query = "Execute EMP_PAY_ATT_Selection @Month, @Year";

        SqlConnection con = null;
        con = new SqlConnection(str);

        SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(query, con);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Month", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Month);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Year);

        SqlDataReader sdr;

        con.Open();

        sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (sdr.Read())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(sdr);
            dataGridView_Report.DataSource = dt;

            dataGridView_Report.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            dataGridView_Report.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView_Report.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView_Report.Rows.Clear();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception es)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
    }
}
```

Again, when running this, it only returns 2 rows on the datagridview. While it should be 3 rows.

These are the tables:

[image]

[image]

Comment: `sdr.Read()` consumes one row and advances the reader. Do not call it if you want to pass the reader to `dt.Load`.

Comment: I see. Never knew that. how about sdr.HasRows()? I mean, I want the if statement to check for returned values.

Comment: Just replaced sdr.Read() with sdr.HasRows and it solved the problem. Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`DbDataReader.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdatareader.read?view=netframework-4.7#System_Data_Common_DbDataReader_Read) method advances the reader to the next record.

There is no way to rewind a data reader. Any methods that you pass it to will have to use it from whatever record it is currently on.

If you want to pass the reader to `DataTable.Load()`, do not `Read` from it yourself. If you merely want to know if it contains records, use [`HasRows`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows?view=netframework-4.7#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataReader_HasRows).